# Why is SOLR's QueryElevation component not working?

Tags: solr, elevation

I have configured the QueryElevation component as here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

And I can see that it is doing something...

In the debug (formatted as JSON) output:

```
 "debug":{
  "queryBoosting":{
    "q":"bar",
    "match":["id:test"]},
```

However, it is having no effects on the query results *whatsoever*

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

I had set the wrong field up as UniqueKey:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field